Report Passing a Parameter from Form
I have a form, L3Process5, with a control 'L3List'.   I want to make a report with the criteria L3Process2.ID equal to the selected value of the control 'L3List'.  For some reason when I call the report using a button on the form, I get prompted for an input, which means it's not getting the value of the control. I do have 6 subreports in my main report if that makes a difference.  This is just one subreport.
SELECT L4Process.L4Process, L3Process2.ID
FROM L4Process INNER JOIN L3Process2 ON L4Process.ID = L3Process2.L4ProcessStep.Value
WHERE (((L3Process2.ID)=[Forms]![L3Process5]![L3List]));






I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I apply filter to report when opening. Are you filtering main report or each subreport?

Please post the SQL of your query in the body of your post and not as an image. See SQL mode in Query Design. We need to see how you are referencing the form control.

I know how to set a filter on report open, but how do I access that filter value in the form? If I have my filter as ID=10 I can't get the report to only open the ID 10.

Parfait  I added the SQL.  By the way, if I put a number in that criteria box, it works

Code shown should work if [L3Process5] is NOT a subform and L3List is NOT a multi-select listbox.

What parameter name is being prompted for input? The entire [Forms]!...? We may need to see a screenshot of this control on form.

@Parfait...I've added some screenshots

These parameter dialogs indicate that either something is very broken in this database, or the problem is with the Multivalued fields. Which are kinda evil.

Very broken. Never seen anything like it. Consider posting in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

I think maybe it was because I had 6 subforms, which did not recognize my list box.

I was using a query as the RecordSource.  When I used the L3List variable in VBA, it was recognized, so I just needed to programmatically set the RecordSource for each subreport.
